# Changing .htaccess changining middle

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've changed the structure for my site now it's a lot cleaner, but google is showing users 404 pages on the old links (learning curve for me!)

I need to write in my .htaccess something that will divert the users to the new path.

The old path is www.example.net/designer-clothing/bags/hype-burgundy-backpack/

but there are hundreds of subcategories e.g. bags, shirts, jeans etc.

I know I can use:

```
Redirect 301 /designer-clothing/bags/ /product/
```

But I'd have to list each subcategory, is there some code that I could use to replace `/designer-clothing/*/` with `/product/`

Or if the path equals `/designer-clothing/bags/hype-burgundy-backpack/` then then take the last part of the url (`hype-burgundy-backpack`) and append it onto `http://example.net/product/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^designer-clothing/[^/]+/(.+)$ /products/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the accepted answer above, you may also use **RedirectMatch** directive for this redirection

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/designer-clothing/[^/]+/(.+)/?$ http://example.com/products/$1
```